# What does "referred" mean in the commitment phase page in Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, commitment-phase

I see that in the [commitment phase page in a proposed Stack Exchange site in Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245?phase=commitment) associated with each committed user, there is a "referred" counter and sometimes a "referred by" indicator.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is coming from the first stage of the proposal, definition, where it gathers followers.

In the [definition page of the proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245?phase=definition), there is a  Share This link:

> [image]

Clicking it gives a link you can send to other people, asking them to follow the proposal:

> [image]

Let's take a good look in the URL:

```
https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics?referrer=rxeOxDcLZH87-8rvo-w82Q2
```

As you can see, there is a special  value there, called "referrer", which is unique and based on the user currently logged in to Area 51.

When someone browse to this URL they see something like this:

> [image]

This is the result of the query string value. Now when following the proposal will add 1 to the "referred" count of the referring user, and show "referred by" to the user who followed.

Comment: I don't see the "Share This" link. Did you do something special ?

Comment: @bli it exists only in the definition phase, not commitment. Sure that when you go [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245?phase=definition) you don't see it? Can you take a screenshot? Also, note this won't "work" in proposals that passed the definition phase.

Comment: I confirm that I went to the "definition" page, where your link also directs me, and that I see nothing under the number of followers, contrary to your screenshot. The proposal indeed passed the definition phase. But then, it is strange that you have the link.

Comment: @bli weird indeed. Try visiting it with Incognito mode of the browser.

Comment: Even in incognito mode I don't have the "Share This" link. But maybe one needs to have a user account to "Share This", and of course I'm not logged in in a fresh incognito Firefox window.

Comment: @bli I see this while not logged in as well. You probably have some adblock or userscript then that hide elements in your pages.